# Correct way to instantiate a Room database in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am writing my first Android application in Kotlin.
I was wondering how to instantiate a Room Persistence database so that I can access it from many different activities.
Sorry if my question is dumb and not too specific, but I'm not sure what details may be useful.

Comment: if you use it in java copy and paste Android studio will convert to kotlin

Comment: This sample project showcases a lot of jetpack stuff in kotlin: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower

Comment: I dunno how to do it in java @ALTegani

Comment: @harisont Don't knock yourself in your own question! You're asking for a bruising that way. Just keep to the specifics and see what answer comes back. I'm going to tweak your post just a little bit to help. Good luck!

Comment: @harisont let me also direct you to [https://android.stackexchange.com/](https://android.stackexchange.com/). Try to pick the most related stackexchange site and your questions will likely be better received.

Answer (score 4):

Try this way..
make app level activity like below for database creation.

```
class AppActivity:Application() {
companion object {
    var db: AppDatabase? = null
    fun getDatabase(): AppDatabase? {
        return db
    }

}
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    db= Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java,"DB").allowMainThreadQueries().build()
}

}
```

after that this activity define in manifest in application tag..

```
        android:name=".app.AppActivity"
```

after that make dao class..

```
@Dao
interface TodoDao {
@Query("SELECT * FROM Todo")
fun getTodoData()= mutableListOf<Todo>()

@Insert
fun insertTodo(todo: Todo)

@Update
fun updateTodo(todo: Todo)

@Delete
fun deleteTodo(todo: Todo)
```

}

make database class for access all dao class..

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(User::class,Assignment::class,Todo::class,   Student::class,Event::class,Comment::class,Feedback::class ,Achivement::class,Note::class, Syllabus::class, Education::class, Mark::class, UserWork::class, Exam::class), version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
abstract fun getUser(): UserDao
abstract fun getStudent(): StudentDao
abstract fun getEducationDao(): EducationDao
abstract fun getWorkDetails(): UserWorkDao
abstract fun getExamDao(): ExamDao
abstract fun getMarkDao(): MarkDao
abstract fun getSyllabusDao(): SyllabusDao
abstract fun getNoteDao(): NoteDao
abstract fun getAchivement():AchivementDao
abstract fun getFeedbackDao():FeedbackDao
abstract fun getCommentDao():CommentDao
abstract fun getEventDao():EventDao
abstract fun getAssignDao():AssignmentDao
abstract fun getTodoDao():TodoDao
 }
```

make table for todo..

```
@Entity
class Todo {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
var id:Int=0
var time:String=""
var activityName:String=""
var hours:String=""
var types:String=""

}
```

after in activity or fragment insert data like below..

```
  var data=Todo().apply {
                time=mSpTime?.selectedItem.toString()
                types=mSpTypes?.selectedItem.toString()
                activityName=mEtAname?.text.toString().trim()
                hours=mEtHour?.text.toString().trim()
          }
   AppActivity.getDatabase()?.getTodoDao()?.insertTodo(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create instance using `companion object`like this,

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(UserEntity::class), version = 1)
abstract class UserDb : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao

    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE: UserDb? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): UserDb? {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized(UserDb::class) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, UserDb::class.java, "user.db").build()
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE
        }

        fun destroyInstance() {
            INSTANCE = null
        }
    }
}
```

You can get instance of db in your activity like this,

`UserDb.getInstance(this)`

Alternatively, you can also use dependency injection libraries like [Dagger](https://google.github.io/dagger/)

Comment: Downvoted for using a Singleton pattern inside a companion object. That's bad practice

Comment: @Zun can you expand more? I see a lot of snippets with exactly this pattern. Actually I don't understand what you mean by singleton pattern either. I'm using this pattern too and would like to understand the issues with it.

Comment: @sprajagopal a companion object is already a singleton. Creating a singleton inside a singleton is useless and waste of code! The modern approach would actually be to register the Room Database singleton through Hilt and inject it wherever you need it (Example: https://svvashishtha.medium.com/using-room-with-hilt-cb57a1bc32f)

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation in [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/), here you will find detailed step by step tutorial about setting up Room.

The correct way to have an instance of the DB is:

```
AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
        AppDatabase.class, "database-name").build();
```

Answer (score -2):

Remember you have to use one more dependency for kotlin and room

```
// Room
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"

apply plugin: "kotlin-android"

apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android-extensions"
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, or am I missing something?